# Is it possible to use the root function to attack RSA?

Tags: rsa

Sorry for my silly question, but I have some doubts on this point. I'm trying to explain it better with an example.

Suppose you use RSA to sign a package and you have the public key. If the signature is generated by the server with its secret key you are able to decipher it because you have the public key and verify the integrity of your package. Suppose I make a "fake" package and I'm able to create a correct signature like this:

```
00 01 FF .. .. FF 00 ASN.1 SHA1
```

due to the deciphering process:

```
cleartext = C^e mod n
```

I can encrypt my signature in this way:

```
C mod n = root(cleartext,e)
```

and make a correctly padded signature without knowing the private key?

Example:

```
e = public exponent = 3

C mod n = cubicroot (cleartext)
```

Comment: But `e` is not already known? Isn't `e` the public exponent?

Comment: How do you propose to calculate that `root` function?

Answer (score 1):

If `root` is just [the function from calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root), then

at most `ceil(root(n,3))` elements `cleartext` of ​ {0,1,2,3,...,n-2,n-1}

are such that `root(cleartext,3)` is an integer

and
when its output is not an integer, that output is not a valid signature,

since valid signatures must be elements of ​ {0,1,2,3,...,n-2,n-1}

.

If `root` is [modular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Integers_modulo_n), then for carefully chosen large [moduli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) n, there's no publicly known 

feasible *classical* way to have a non-negligible probability of computing `root`.

However, [quantum computers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_computing) change things quite significantly.

Answer (score 0):

Finding the cubic root **modulo `n`** seems to be non-trivial. You may read about it in [StackExchange’s Mathematics site](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/673418/cube-roots-modulo-p).

Nowadays, the 65537 is generally chosen for the public exponent, rather than 3, which probably makes the discrete root more complicated to calculate.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this. But only if you can solve the [discrete logarithm problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm)! 
Your "root" function actually has to find the group element `c` such that `c^e = k` where `c` and `k` are group elements of the group `Z mod n` and e is a natural number.

If you can find an efficient implementation of such a function, you will become very famous.

Comment: `e` is known, the OP wants to compute `C`.

Comment: As CodesInChaos said, this is **not** the discrete logarithm problem. The discrete logarithm problem would be to find `e` knowing `c` and `k` while, here, you have to find `c` knowing `e` and `k`.